# Keyframes chaining animation in react animation issue

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am new to css animation , I am trying to slide in a div element and want to slide out of the screen using the keyframes in nextjs. The slide in is working properly and slideout is not working , while inspecting the element I have figured out that keyframes are taking the initial position only not the second value. How can I fix this? . Any help will be appreciated. I have attached the inspect view and code view image below

[image: code view]
[image: inspect view]

I don't know what's wrong in the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards` to make the animation keep the `to` state.

> [Documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) The animation-fill-mode CSS property sets how a CSS animation applies styles to its target before and after its execution.

```
.splashView {
  animation: slideIn 1s 2s ease-in forwards, slideOut 1s 5s ease-out forwards;
}
```

Comment: Actually the above code I have mentioned has worked without adding the animation-fill-mode: forwards , after that I have deleted the next folder inside my app directory and rebuild it. But I don't know how its affecting the animation effects. If anyone knows the answer please do share.